# Why do activities have their own Icon?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a specifici reason why if I have MainActivity, it has it's own Icon, yet if I create SecondActivity it has a separate icon? If I download an app from the Play store it's all from one icon. Am I just being dumb? Or is there a specific reason why this is. Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do individual windows have icons rather than applications?

Comment: i dont know why someone would downvote the question as I find it good. I upvoted it to cancel the downvote :)

Comment: Seva, I can't tell if this is a hypothetical, or a real question. Can you explain it?

Comment: Do you mean your app has two launcher icons in the device's app listing?

Comment: No, Lets say I have Activity a, you press a button in Activity a, and you get send to activity b, however, they both have their own icons on the android desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any activity that declares the following intent filter will have an icon in the system's app listing:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you only want one icon then only put this intent filter inside your main activity.

Comment: Thank you sir! You will be barked as correct as soon as i can!

Answer (score 1):

Each activity can be launched independently - and thereby can have its own icon - in the Launcher. Also, I think in later APIs, the icon can be displayed inside the Activity itself.